# Definition of active measures in a political warfare context

Tags: armed-conflict, terminology, espionage

Is there a good definition of active measures in a political warfare context? [Wikipedia has an article on active measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_measures) in that context, but it lacks a concise definition. Rather than stating a definition it describes different types of active measures.

I'm looking for a succinct definition, perhaps as used in government or law-enforcement. I've searched the [DOD Dictionary of Military and Associated Terms](http://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/dictionary.pdf) but it doesn't list active measures.

Comment: This term is a Russian euphemism for covert attacks and various kinds of terroristic activity on foreign territory. Since it has not been officially condemned (yet), I'm afraid there is **no publicly available formal definition** of this term nor a list of actions that qualify for this definition.

Comment: @bytebuster the term is also used by American counterintelligence (I have no link ready, but I have heard it used in interviews recently). There even used to be an [Active Measures Working Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Measures_Working_Group).

Comment: This terminology is highly context dependent. Your question isn't clear enough to convey what you mean.

Comment: @ohwilleke I tried to clarify it. Is the political warfare context specific enough? If not, please explain the ambiguity or different contexts in political warfare.

Comment: I commented because I couldn't figure out what the heck you were talking about. Perhaps an example or news story would be helpful.

Comment: @ohwilleke the linked Wikipedia page explains it pretty extensively (although it lacks a concise definition like in the DOD dictionary). There are plenty of good examples of active measures, both in fiction (season 7 of Homeland) and in non-fiction ([Mitrokhin Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitrokhin_Archive)). Note that those examples contain instances of active measures, some clearly are, others are a grey area. You'd really need a definition to judge if an action is or isn't it, hence the question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dennis Cux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Kux), a [former Deputy Assistant Secretary of State and in that role the first chairman of the Active Measures Working Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Measures_Working_Group), wrote an [article](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP90-00552R000505100002-0.pdf) on this. I don't know for sure where the article was published originally (but I think it's [this book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CC2AXXI)), but it's now [available on the CIA's website](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP90-00552R000505100002-0.pdf). The quote relevant to the question is (I emphasised parts that I think are especially relevant):

> In Soviet intelligence doctrine, the concept of "active measures" covers a wide span of **practices including disinformation operations, political influence efforts, and the activities of Soviet front groups and foreign communist parties. All active measures have the common goal of enhancing Soviet influence, usually by tarnishing the image of opponents. They generally involve elements of deception and often employ clandestine means to mask Moscow's hand in the operation.**
>
> Overall, where active measures fit in the Soviet framework may be better understood by considering the whole spectrum of Soviet foreign policy endeavors through the optic of "white," "gray," and "black" operations. Normal diplomatic, trade, aid, and informational efforts can be considered "white" or overt activities. "Gray" activities are those involving communist fronts, foreign communist parties, "clandestine" radio stations, or well-known media outlets for disinformation. While not officially acknowledged to be Soviet sponsored, semi-over "gray" activities are widely known as under Soviet direction and control. In contrast, "black" activities involve genuinely clandestine operations: the use of agents of influence, spreading false rumors, duping politicians and journalists, and disseminating forgeries and fake documents.
>
> **Active measures fall under either the "gray" or the "black" rubric, although the line between the semi-overt and the clandestine is often blurred.**